# Сбросить результаты подсчета в fetch после отправки формы

Tags: javascript, fetch

Сделал самописный калькулятор по чистке ковров, прикрутил к ajax-обработчику формы, чтобы данные с калькулятора отправлялись на почту хозяину всей это красоты. Форма отправляется с помощью fetch. Чистый JS, без jQuery. В конструкции .then при успешной отправке использую возможности для очистки калькулятора и сброса некоторых опций которые там есть и показываю сообщение об успешной отправке формы. Вот так:

```
                .then(() => {

                    document.querySelector('.form-submit .form__success').classList.add('show');
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        document.querySelector('.form-submit .form__success').classList.remove('show');
                    }, 5000);

                    document.querySelector('.form-submit').reset();
                    document.querySelector('.delivery__map').classList.contains('show') ?  document.querySelector('.delivery__map').classList.remove('show') : null;
                    document.querySelector('.delivery__porter').classList.contains('show') ?  document.querySelector('.delivery__porter').classList.remove('show') : null;

                    //document.querySelector('#is_dust').checked = true;
                    //document.querySelector('#is_times').checked = true;

                })
```

Все это работает без проблем. Но вот западня с результатами расчета. Калькулятор накидывает их сюда

```
<div class="results">
    <div class="calc-sum__result">Стоимость чистки ковра: <span id="result">300</span><span> руб.</span></div>
    <div class="calc-sum__result">Стоимость доставки: <span id="result-del">0</span><span> руб.</span></div>
    <div class="calc-sum__result">Общая сумма: <span id="result-glob">300</span><span> руб.</span></div>
</div>
```

Почему то не могу никак сбросить эти результаты. Пробовал что-то вроде

```
document.querySelector('#result-glob').textContent = "0";
```

и `innerHTML` а также пробовал JS задавать включенными парочку чекбоксов (там внизу в первом блоке кода закомменчено), так как если после отправки формы сделать это вручную, то результаты сбрасываются к искомым, а вот JSом не хотят. Что делать, как быть?

Вот ссылка, калькулятор этот вверху
http://a0695986.xsph.ru/

Comment: а где у вас эта строка кода (с обнулением) в скрипте?, из консоли же всё нормально работает

Comment: Есть вероятность, что ваша очистка через textContent. срабатывает до какого-нибудь слушателя на самой форме.
Попробуйте накинуть setTimeout. Если сработает, значит хаос в порядке.
Также, когда жмете на кнопку «Отправить» лучше задизейблите форму через pointer-events: none, так как я отправил 5 раз ее. Очень долго отправляется запрос в файл скрипта :)

Comment: Я не указал в скрипте эту строку) что там указывать то...

Comment: Олег, напишите этот коммент как ответ, я приму его... я пробовал settimeout накидывать на checked = true - не работало, а с textContent срабатывает... Спасибо)